# Cursor is interrupted in procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure to iterate over a temporary table querying information in 4 more tables and then storing in one or another table.

I am sure that my 5 tables are populated, but the loop only happens once, the select in the table 'volume' only returns me null, but when I get the information and make the query there is the regit.

Can someone tell me why my loop is only returning once, and why is this select returning empty?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS problem_expedition;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE problem_expedition ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE t_codSerie varchar (255);
  DECLARE t_codProd varchar (255);
  DECLARE t_codBatch varchar (255);
  DECLARE id_batch bigint (20);
  DECLARE id_volume bigint (20);
  DECLARE product_id bigint (20);
  DECLARE id_historical bigint (20);

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE cursor_p CURSOR FOR SELECT codProd, codBatch, codSerie from volume_confirmed;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN cursor_p;
  interno_get: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_p INTO t_codProd, t_codBatch, t_codSerie;
    IF v_finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE interno_get;
    END IF;

    SELECT id INTO product_id FROM product WHERE code = t_codProd;
    SELECT id INTO id_batch FROM batch WHERE code = t_codLote AND product_id = product_id;
    SELECT id into id_volume from volume WHERE volume.serial = t_codSerie and volume.batch_id = id_batch and volume.producto_id = product_id;
    SELECT CONCAT ("Searching volume: (", t_codSerie, "-", id_batch, "-", product_id, ").") AS debug;

    SET id_historical = 0;
    SELECT id INTO id_historical from historical where volume_id = id_volume and (action like 'EXPEDICAO' OR action like 'CONFERENCE');

    IF id_historical> 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO with_expedition (t_codProd, t_codBatch, t_codSerie, volume_id, historical_id) VALUES (t_codProd, t_codBatch, t_codSerie, volume_id, historical_id);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO without_expedition (t_codProd, t_codBatch, t_codSerie, id_volume) VALUES (t_codProd, t_codBatch, t_codSerie, id_volume);
    END IF;

  END LOOP internal_get;
  CLOSE cursor_p;

END |
DELIMITER;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
mysql> SELECT * from without_expedition\G
*************************** 1. row ****
 t_codProd: CP 3400-H
 t_codBatch: O100151787
t_codSerie: 1950
 id_volume: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> CALL problem_expedition();
+--------------------------------------------+
| debug                                      |
+--------------------------------------------+
 - 38196 - 414). |me: (1950
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.14 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM product WHERE code = 'CP 3400-H';
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 414 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM batch WHERE code = 'O100151787' AND produto_id=414;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 38196 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
mysql>  SELECT id from volume WHERE serial like '1950' and batch_id=38196 and product_id=414;
+---------+
| id      |
+---------+
| 5910621 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

If you look at my output you will see that I have a volume with id 5910621, but in the procedure it only returns me null

**UPDATE**

I made a test by leaving it inside my loop as follows:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS problem_expedition;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE problem_expedition ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE t_codSerie varchar (255);
  DECLARE t_codProd varchar (255);
  DECLARE t_codBatch varchar (255);
  DECLARE id_batch bigint (20);
  DECLARE id_volume bigint (20);
  DECLARE product_id bigint (20);
  DECLARE id_historical bigint (20);

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE cursor_p CURSOR FOR SELECT codProd, codBatch, codSerie from volume_confirmed;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN cursor_p;
  interno_get: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_p INTO t_codProd, t_codBatch, t_codSerie;
    IF v_finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE interno_get;
    END IF;

    SELECT id INTO product_id FROM product WHERE code = t_codProd;
    SELECT id INTO id_batch FROM batch WHERE code = t_codLote AND product_id = product_id;
    SELECT CONCAT ("Searching volume: (", t_codSerie, "-", t_codBatch, "-", t_codProd, ").") AS debug;

  END LOOP internal_get;
  CLOSE cursor_p;

END |
DELIMITER;
```

That way the loop has rolled all the data, I did some other tests, and actually the error is in my line with the volume table, because even if I leave my code complete and change the line to something:

```
SELECT id INTO id_volume FROM volume limit 1
```

The loop only runs once, and I check the without_expedition table, it has a valid volume value.

Does anyone know what may be happening from a query in a table that is affecting the v_finisher or handler variable?

**UPDATE 2**

I made the following change in my code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS problem_expedition;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE problem_expedition ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE t_codSerie varchar (255);
  DECLARE t_codProd varchar (255);
  DECLARE t_codLote varchar (255);
  DECLARE id_lote bigint (20);
  DECLARE id_volume bigint (20);
  DECLARE product_id bigint (20);
  DECLARE id_historico bigint (20);

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE cursor_volumes CURSOR FOR
    SELECT codProd, codlote, codSeries from volume_id;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN cursor_volumes;
  interno_get: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_volumes INTO t_codProd, t_codLote, t_codSerie;
    IF v_finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE interno_get;
    END IF;

    SELECT id INTO product_id FROM product WHERE code = t_codProd;
    SELECT id INTO id_lote FROM batch WHERE code = t_codLote AND product_id = product_id;
    SELECT CONCAT ("Searching volume:", t_codSerie, "-", id_lote, "-", product_id) AS debug;
    SELECT id INTO id_volume FROM volume AS v WHERE v.serial like t_codSerie and v.lote_id = id_lote and v.product_id = product_id limit 1;

    SET id_historical = 0;
    SELECT id INTO historical_id from historical where volume_id = volume_id and action in ('EXPEDITION', 'CONFERENCE') limit 1;

    IF id_historical> 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO com_expedition (t_codProd, t_codLote, t_codSerie, volume_id, historical_id) VALUES (t_codProd, t_codLote, t_codSerie, volume_id, historical_id);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO sem_expedition (t_codProd, t_codLote, t_codSerie, id_volume) VALUES (t_codProd, t_codLote, t_codSerie, id_volume);
    END IF;

  END LOOP internal_get;
  CLOSE cursor_volumes;

END |
DELIMITER;
```

From what I realized my loop is interrupted by the fact that the query in the volume table is returning nothing, why this happens seems to be with the variable `t_codSerie`, so much so that it also damages the `Concat` function that returns the output in a strange way

Comment: there is the regit? What?